# log4j properties doesn't apply after upgrading zookeeper from 3.6.3 to 3.9.1

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

In my Java project I have log4j2.xml file under recources which defines the logs format and logs level for each service of `camel, kafka, zookeeper, springframework`.
 I set a timestamp before each log and set `level="ERROR"` for all the services above.
I had apache zookeeper version 3.6.3 as part of kafka and not a direct dependency in my pom.xml.
Because of a vulnerability found in this version I decided to upgrade this version to 3.9.1 by adding a new dependency of zookeeper to my pom.xml.
Before upgrading zookeeper, when I ran `docker logs [myservice]`, this would be one of the logs:
`[30/01/24 10:14:15:015 UTC] [qtp2593515078-66]  INFO BusinessLogic: createReport - Started`
After upgrading, this is a log example:
`[pool-3-thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds`
Two things changed, one is that the logs aren't according to the format anymore (no timestamp before each log) and the log level seems to be changed from error to info for the services, which means that the log4j2.xml properties isn't applied anymore.
What I tried to do:

1. Changed the zookeeper version to 3.7.2, 3.8.3
2. Excluding `ch.qos.logback` and `io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static`

Answer (score 1):

zookeeper could bring in another logging implementation as a transient dependency that overwrites log4j, look for that and exclude any logging dependencies you find.

Comment: After the exclusions that I added, zookeeper brings only audience-annotations and netty-handler, exactly like zookeeper 3.6.3.
I compared the two dependency trees of before and after the update and couldn't see any new libraries :(

Comment: try to log this to find out what the the runtime logging provider is: log.info(log.getClass().getName());